# Which files shouldn't be checked in into version control in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea, gitignore, android-studio

I have used Eclipse IDE with the Android SDK Tools in the past, and now I'm migrating to Android Studio. Android Studio generates a lot of files, like `build.gradle`. Which files/folders should I add to the `.gitignore` file?

EDIT: A lot of questions here give different answers. So I've tried to combine them, using various sources.

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iws
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
```