# Which files should I add to SVN ignore for an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, svn, ide, intellij-idea, android-studio

In Eclipse, I had the custom of adding bin and gen directories to SVN ignore. But now, using Android Studio (based on IntelliJ IDEA), which files should I ignore?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should be in my .gitignore for an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I added the following items in my `.gitignore`, it should be the same for SVN:

- gradle
- .idea
- *.iml
- build
- .DS_Store (for mac only)

Comment: On the docs it's said that do should put *.iml files to version-control: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1186

Why do you ignore them?

Comment: Thanks, I also added the lines on this [link](http://th4t.net/android-studio-gitignore.html)

Comment: The docs also say to include 
`"All the files under .idea directory in the project root except the workspace.xml and tasks.xml files which store user specific settings"`
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067

Comment: What about the ".gradle" folder?

Comment: You can also ignore the "local.properties" file, since it is just an auto generated file that points to the android-sdk directory on your computer.

Comment: how about the `gradlew`?

Comment: The .idea folder includes the ".gitignore" file, should we just ignore the whole folder?

Answer (score 18):

See this IntelliJ IDEA KB article: ["How to manage projects under Version Control Systems"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems).

Add to Subversion:

- all files under `/.idea` directory in the project root but ignore **workspace.xml** and **tasks.xml**,
- all .iml module files.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. The files under .idea should be included and also the .iml files.

Comment: As replied by "Serge Baranov" on same thread, 



it would depend on the project you are using. If the project is Maven or Gradle based and these library files are generated automatically on import, you can exclude them from the version control. When the libraries are configured manually by the user, they should be shared.

Answer (score 11):

I've used the following SVN ignore list sucessfully:

```
.gradle
local.properties
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
build
```

The ignore should be applied recursively.

Reference: [Same question, for git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: app/build should be ignored too.