# Android Studio SVN gradle

Tags: android, svn, gradle, android-studio

I've used Eclipse and the Subclipse plugin to program for Android. Now I've switched to Android Studio, but for me this Subversion stuff in Android Studio is a pain in the ass.

Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but when projects are checked out on different machines the gradle project settings are overwritten. Settings in 'local.properties', '.idea/gradle.xml' and '.idea/workspace.xml'. Maybe others too.
This means checking out an Android Studio project from a different machine gives me a project with lots of errors.
I guess this is not how it's supposed to work.

Am I doing something basically wrong with Android Studio and Subversion?

Can anybody outline the steps to work with Android Studio and Subversion correctly?

Comment: Android Studio is a bundle version of IntelliJ IDEA so it should be compatible with SVN. Have a look at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html for more info. Please also have a look the this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940934/what-files-should-i-add-to-svn-ignore-in-an-project-using-android-studio to see what workspace file to include or not in svn

Comment: Thanks for your comment buzeeg. Before posting my question I did some searchs on the web and came across both sites you mentioned. Checking in a project with these SVN ignore files is (at least for me) tricky with android studio. But the Problem is checking out the Project. You will hve to generate a new Project with the correct settings and afterwards check the stuff out from svn. This seems ugly to me. But Android Studio is still a "Preview" so no complaint ...

Comment: Yes it is tricky. I generaly import my git repo as a new Project, but some settings might be lost.