# Which files to commit to version contrl svn in Android Studio project

Tags: android, svn, version-control, android-studio

I have a Android Studio project and when I make changes to the project I commit the whole project to the version control. Now when I want to checkout the latest version from my version control on another device, Android Studios has problems opening, building and running the application. So my question is: Which files should I commit (or Ignore) in order to checkout.

Also, when two persons on different devices work on the same file and they commit their work. Can the files be merged?

Comment: Dupe of numerous similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940934/what-files-should-i-add-to-svn-ignore-in-an-project-using-android-studio/16983374#16983374

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore all .class files and all workspace configuration files.

Here's a list you may want to use:
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build