# Which files to ignore using to commit to SVN in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, ignore

Which files do i have to put on ignore in SVN when im using Android Studio?

Currently i have ignored this files:

*.idea
gradle
*.iml
build
local.properties
.DS_Store

Comment: The same files you'd ignore using any other version control system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create an Android Studio project, .gitignore files will be also generated.
Based on that, in the parent folder we exclude:

```
-.gradle
-/local.properties
-/.idea/workspace.xml
-.DS_Store
```

And in the modules directory:

```
-/build
```

Comment: He is talking about SVN not GIT!

Comment: He did said "based on that"...which means we can figure out which files should be ignored in SVN (and any other source code repository) "based on that"....I found this answer very helpful to know what to ignore for my SVN repository. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Personally when I'm working on Android project I ignore the folder bin , project.property, classpath, settins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.pref , proguard-project.txt , local.properties .

I don't use Ant or Maven so maybe there are others files to ignore.

Comment: The question is about Android Studio, not Eclipse.