# Where to write ignore list while importing SVN repository in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

My Android Studio project is successfully built and works fine on phone. However, I'm not able to import the module into a subversion repository easily. The problem is that:

I don't know how to add the list of files to ignore. I have looked into some of the questions already asked here, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487608/which-files-to-ignore-using-to-commit-to-svn-in-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887881/what-is-the-right-way-to-import-an-android-studio-project-in-a-svn-repository) and all the linked questions from them. However most of them are talking about `.gitignore`. So, far I have tried all of the following:

1. Created a `.gitignore` file with list of files to ignore
2. Added entries under `Android Studio > Preferences > Version Control > Ignored Files`

In every case, I mentioned `bin`, `built` and `gen` folders among others. None of the above has worked as every time I start importing, at some point it starts importing the files I want to ignore. Since no file is ignored the import process lasts insanely long. Eclipse was far better with this respect. I have never looked into ignore files at all!

I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore is for git -- an alternate and possibly more powerful source control tool.  I've used both and I'd highly recommend moving to git if possible.

Otherwise you will be stuck using the `propset` in svn:

[Equivalent of ".gitignore" file with Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293539/equivalent-of-gitignore-file-with-subversion)