# Android Studio - .iml file changes its name

Tags: git, android-studio

I have kind of a strange problem.

As I have read in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504982/is-it-mandatory-to-save-iml-files-in-version-control) I have to add my `.iml` files to Git, because I am not using Maven.

But the `.iml` file in the Root-Folder changes its name depending on the Foldername the Project is cloned to :

```
Project Cloned to Folder "Test" the iml is --> Test.iml
Project Cloned to Folder "ProjectName"     --> Projectname.iml
```

How should this work, if I have to add the .iml File to Git, because People can clone the repository to whatever folder they like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems impossible to use different names for a tracked file in different repositories.

An alternative may be to keep the project with the `.iml` file in the sub-folder of the `git` root folder. In this way, no matter what folder people clone to, the name of the sub-folder for the project is not changed and so does the `.iml` file.

Comment: So you would put the whole Project in a subdirectory which then gets commited / pushed

Comment: Yes, put the source codes of the project in a sub-directory. You may have `docs`, `test` and any other things in the root folder. I just searched `android` in `github`, and got the first item https://github.com/github/android for your reference. Its project is in a sub-directory called `app`.