# First commit Android Studio Project -- What should leave out?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I am doing my initial commit for a new android project. I am happy with the state of the code but was wondering about which files to add + commit and which files should I leave out.

Here is my .gitignore contents:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/
```

Here is my current git status:

```
.gitignore
.gradle/
app/
build.gradle
build/
gradle/
gradlew
gradlew.bat
import-summary.txt
settings.gradle
```

Comment: If you're using Android Studio - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project

Comment: You can also try to assemble your .gitignore here: https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: @DarekKay  How do you use gitignore.io for the Android Studio Integrated Development Environment (IDE) ?  I can get OS and Android to work fine, but not the IDE. I can't find a selection there that makes any sense for this task.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @zipzit - Just type "Intellij" instead - it's the IDE, which Android Studio is based on.

Comment: If you are using Gradle wrapper and defining your `.gitignore` with the help of [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) be careful to define _Java_ ignore list **before** _Gradle_. Settings for Java will ignore all jar files: `*.jar`. And although Gradle ignore setting defines `!gradle-wrapper.jar`, wrapper jar will still be ignored by your git repository.

Answer (score 4):

I commit everything except the local stuff, this is my .gitignore:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
Dependency/*
/app/.idea/*
/app/.svn/*
/app/local.properties
```

Comment: Why isn't *.gradle ignored?

Comment: I don't want the .gradle folder to be included (nor its contents), this does that for me.

Comment: Should build.gradle, settings.gradle, or build.common.gradle be ignored?