# Updating android project from bitbucket causes binary merge conflicts

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-studio, bitbucket

I'm in the process of learning android development and I want to be able to develop from work, home or my laptop so it made sense to use github or bitbucket as a central repository. I chose bitbucket so I didn't have to learn in public so to speak.

I was not able to get bitbucket to work within android-studio but I didn't mind dropping out to the command line for my pushes and pulls.

Pushing works fine and cloning works pretty well (some settings need to get adjusted for the local environment but that not been a problem.)

However, I'm finding as I start to iterate on a project I'm getting merge conflicts on binary files such as:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

I guess it makes some sense but I don't know what to do about it. Do I have to set something so that git ignores certain files? How do I know which ones? It's certainly not all binary files since I do want to store app related graphics.

If I tried again to get this working natively in Android Studio (some people can do it apparently) would Android Studio protect me from these errors?

Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be committing your apk files, or any built stuff.

I use this this .gitignore by taken directly from an answer [here by user Lior Iluz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# OSX files
.DS_Store

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Android Studio
*.iml
.idea
#.idea/workspace.xml - remove # and delete .idea if it better suit your needs.
.gradle
build/
```