# Import Android Studio project from git into Android Studio (Gradle)

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle

I've been reading this for hours now and everyone seems to have a different approach or that the tutorials are out of date.

Android Studio .gitignore only includes the app directory, this is on purpose. For what reason I do not know. When trying to clone the git repo Android Studio does not know how to handle it. A very annoying flaw in Android Studio.

[What should be in my .gitignore for an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)

I have a remote git repo containing the project in the form:

[image]

as you can see the git repo contains the `/app` directory.

I then try to import it via `Check out project from Version Control` and select `git`:

[image]

Everything works, the `Test` is successful and then I click on `Clone`:

[image]

The next part I press `Yes` as git did not clone the entire project but just the essential source files:

[image]

This is the part where I am lost, I am guessing I am to create the project via `Gradle`, so I select `Gradle` and press `Next`:

[image]

What am I supposed to do here, there are apparently gradle files on the net but which one am I supposed to use:

[image]

### Create project from existing sources

If I choose `Create project from existing sources` I get the following problem:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Results in this, I was expecting `app` directory:

[image]

File structure (as you can see fela is missing a lot of files, this is when I chose create project from existing sources, MyApplication is an example of an app which was created in Android Studio):

[image]

Comment: "Create project from existing sources" - doesn't work?

Comment: @Divers It does but then Android Studio complains about migrating to Gradle, which makes non sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is obvious when looking at the `.gitignore` file of a newly created project. The `build.gradle` file **is** and **should** be included in the push to the remote repo.

So the person who made the repo in my question is doing it wrong. The `.gitignore` file includes:

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

As seen, more files should of been uploaded to the remote repo.

Comment: Where is the gitignore file? I am having same issue :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188849/git-clone-not-working-on-android-studio/31188913?noredirect=1#comment50383322_31188913

Comment: @Fearghal The .gitignore file is a *hidden* file, so it might not be visible. It is however visible in Android Studio. The .gitignore file is located in the root directory of your project, for example: .../AndroidStudioProjects/myProject/.gitignore

Comment: thx Karl. I am not sure what you did with the git ignore. I am having same issue with getting a project to compile and run. I have o Gradle file (that i can see) and when i open a specific folder with code it asks me to define the Gradle file. Can you out line what you did with the gitignore file?

Comment: You have not included the correct `.gitignore` file recommendations. Please include it. As this answer says that `.gradle` should be included in `.gitignore` file. However question in this page shows a problem when `.gradle` is included in `.gitignore`. Please clarify this. I am also having similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Existing Sources instead of Import

Answer (score 0):

IF your project is showing error like `The project 'xxxxxxx-xx' is not a Gradle-based project` then check this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html). I hope it helps. This link might cover your possible problem. Let me know the progress.

Comment: Updated question. The link didn't really help as the git project was originally made in Android Studio. So it should work.