# Android Studio not recognising Gradle projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

No matter what projects I import they never work - Android Studio is always flagging `this is not a Gradle build project`.

I select `VCS -> GIT` and clone the repo without any problem. I then go through the wizard with no issues (I select `create project from existing sources`), creating my code base with a warning, below.  When i try to run throws all sorts of errors.

> Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build
>   system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build
>   system. More Information about migrating to Gradle.
>
> Don't show this message again.

When I go to the link it makes no sense whatever to me, it says to create an arbitrary Gradle file and populate it with my references (I think), which is out of my understanding. I shouldnt have to do this as it says in the repository instructions that it is in fact a Gradle-based project.

The project I am trying to clone is
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location.git

Can anybody tell me specifically how to import and run the following git repo in Android studio for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok from the start (as i dont know what  other way works)

- Go to Git master page (it has 'download to zip' or 'clone to desktop' button). use https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location as a test master page if you like to ensure you have no other issues i did not.
- Click 'download zip'
- Unzip the project
- Close the current project in Android Studio -> File/Close Projects
- A popup screen like this will appear, choose Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle etc.)
- You will be asked to select the project, select your unzipped project within the master folder, eg basicLocation
- Select 'create project from existing resources' default
- dont change project name (may cause issues)
- Next through 'import project -> directories'
- Next through project -> libraries
- Next Through import projects -> modules and module dependencies
- Next through import project ->SDK
- Next through import project ->manifest.xmls
- Android Studio starts. Ensure the configurations dropdown has a project in it called 'app' app
- Select 'sync Gradle' icon (green circle)
- May get language warning, ignore or accept restart, doesnt matter

At bottom it should now say 'Gradle executing tasks' after which it will run on device or emulator :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: File > Open > the build.gradle file you just cloned with the repo

I just wanted to add this, because I had the same problem, and even if Fearghal´s answer and comments pointed me in the right direction, I think he may have added unnecesary extra steps, i.e. Download as ZIP, Close current project, etc.

Simply put, you VCS > Git Clone, and then open the build.gradle file. That´s it

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for many reasons.  I typically see it when I move the directory.  The easiest way I have found is to close the project and then reopen it using "Import project (Gradle, Eclipse, ADT, etc.) menu item then selecting the folder.  This will force it to reimport the project and fix any metadata/configs.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

On Android Studio

Open the settings.gradle file

include your project

include ':myproject'

Answer (score -2):

Well, as Android Studio correctly says, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location is not a Gradle project.

Any subdirectory of that repository is however.
They are different projects.

So clone that repository and import one of its subdirectory in Gradle.

Comment: thx for response. 'So clone that repository and import one of its subdirectory in Gradle.' How do i do that? Select one of the child folders and import it eg https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates ???

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates will of course not work in Android Studio: it is *not* a Git repository

Comment: You just clone the git repository and in Android Studio select *anypath/android-play-location/theprojectiwant*...

Comment: Im sorry, the solution is pretty simple to you but i am lost. I have cloned the repo. I see all files in my Android Studio explorer. Now do you mean i have gone too far and should have only selected one project to clone or do you mean i select a project in explorer and drill down into java (which is fuull of errors) and do something there. Please take it in baby steps

Comment: Ok so i didnt think i would have to open the file specifically considering i can see it in explorer but.... file->open select my 'basicLocation' and now im presented with 'import project from Gradle' with a blank browse control beside 'Gradle location' . Any ideas on that?

Comment: Maybe you can try to import and run and see if it works straight off or if its a repo issue?

Comment: I just did: went to github, downloaded as zip, unziped, opened *BasicLocationSample* project from Android Studio and it compiles and runs on my Nexus 5... Took me 30s.

Comment: I copied you. downloaded as zip, unziped, opened BasicLocationSample project from Android Studio <b>Import project from gradle</b> where i do not have anything to put in the 'Gradle home' broswe

Comment: Ok so your suggestion did not work. 'Opening' the preferred target was incorrect if by 'open' you mean file->open, i had to 'import' the target and then sync the project. I will detail the answer below.