# How to import github project to my android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

When I want to import github project to my android studio ,
I see this error:

[image: SDK location not found]

How to solve it?

Comment: have you added sdk path to environment variable?

Comment: This error message makes good sense to an experienced programmer, but apparently not to you.   Could you please explain what you understand, and what does not make sense of the text in the dialogue box?

Comment: hi (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127943/import-android-studio-project-from-git-into-android-studio-gradle)is a good teach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open control panel
Properties -> advancedsystemsettings
Then go to Change Environment Variables
Then click create a new environment variables
Create a new variable named ANDROID_HOME path C:\Android\sdk

Answer (score 2):

Change the SDK path in local.properties to your installed SDK's Path.