# Android studio cannot ignore gradle_project_sync_data.bin

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I have slowly started to move my project to Android Studio since Google announced that they won't support Eclipse anymore.

I have enabled version control, added my remote and added git ignore file from [What should be in my .gitignore for an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project) and it seems to work fine apart from 2 annoying files

build/intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml
build/intermediates/gradle_project_sync_data.bin

According to my git ignore both should be ignored but they are not

What am I doing wrong?

here is my gitignore

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

Comment: Any chance of seeing your gitignore file?

Comment: Did you ever committed those files already before changing the gitignore?

Comment: yes but I have also applied http://stackoverflow.com/a/23839198/74896