# Ideal Android Studio gitignore file

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket, gitignore

i recently created an Android project but it is my first time to work with Android Studio, i placed the project in a Git folder to be able work with another developer remotely through Git and i found that the default .gitignore file contains the following:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

i just wondering is this the ideal gitignore file to be able work together remotely? or i have to edit or remove some files from it?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be in my .gitignore for an Android Studio project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As for me, ideal gitignore file is:

```
### Android ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

### Android Patch ###
gen-external-apklibs


### Java ###
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*


### Intellij ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio

*.iml

## Directory-based project format:
.idea/
# if you remove the above rule, at least ignore the following:

# User-specific stuff:
# .idea/workspace.xml
# .idea/tasks.xml
# .idea/dictionaries

# Sensitive or high-churn files:
# .idea/dataSources.ids
# .idea/dataSources.xml
# .idea/sqlDataSources.xml
# .idea/dynamic.xml
# .idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle:
# .idea/gradle.xml
# .idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin:
# .idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.ipr
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ
/out/
/captures

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
```

Also you can use awesome service: https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: '*.class' entry is defined more than once :)