# Android Studio: a lot of Gradle tasks missing after import

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-import

I have an **Android Studio project** that I **imported in SVN**. I didn't add some files like the *build* folder, *local.properties*, the *.idea* folder and *.gradle* folder, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project).  Then I **checked out the project** in another directory on my machine and **imported it into Android Studio**.

After the import, I tried to clean the project, but the option wasn't present in the GUI. I found it weird so I checked the list tasks with `./gradlew tasks` and the ouput was indeed quite short (help tasks not shown):

> ### Build Setup tasks
>
> init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
>
> wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

In the original project, here are a lot of other tasks (Android, build, install, verficitation and other tasks). Has anyone a clue on what is going on here ? The weird thing is that I just did the same procedure with another project and didn't get any problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my case there wasn't anything wrong with my `settings.gradle` file. If someone is still searching the solution, try to do [these steps from my answer on similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517138/11535782)

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out what the problem was.

After the import, the **settings.gradle** couldn't resolve some of the dependencies. I had some lines like

```
project(':apps').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Libraries/apps')
```

Which I had to modify to

```
 project(':apps').projectDir = new File(/home/path/to/workspace/Libraries/apps')
```

I will just leave to here if someone needs it.