# Git don't able to upload .iml file(from android studio)

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

Hi i am development a android project by android studio.I want more developer work in this project into same time.For this i try to upload this project into Bitbucket by create a repository .I can able to upload/pull this project but i don't able to upload .iml file(2 file).For this if any developer want to upload then he fail .it show a error.Which i share a screen.

[image]

I am sure it causes when i upload the project by repository then the project *.iml file don't commit for this when any one try to import then it show this error.There is any way when i upload the project then all project file will be upload/commit(such as .iml)

Comment: This sounds like perhaps the other engineer whose work you pulled did not include the `.iml` files, hence Android Studio cannot finish loading the entire project.  Can you confirm this?

Comment: Hello @TimBiegeleisen when i pulled the whole project then i don't able any option or for  selected any way to  *iml file pull .For this i don't able to pull thi s.my query is how i  will get the option to pull .iml file when i upload the project into repository(At first)

Answer (score 0):

Add `*.iml` to `.gitignore`, you **don't need those files** to successfully **import** and **compile** the **project**.

> IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA, an IDE used to develop
>   Java applications. It stores information about a development module,
>   which may be a Java, Plugin, Android, or Maven component; saves the
>   module paths, dependencies, and other settings.

Comment: I already add this but don't able to load/syn. whole code.Please see my screen which i share  this link.http://imgur.com/8WZzGUg  .you can understand my problem

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if if the project / .idea / .name file has the same name as the android project