# android sdk dir conflict when multiple developers involved

Tags: android, android-studio

Let say there are two developers: john and james.
john's sdk is in C:/user/john/android/sdk
james's sdk is in C:/user/james/android/sdk

Each time syncing to git with the whole project.
Then if last time john do the sync, james fetch and open project with warning "sdk location not found, change to james/android/sdk.
Android studio automatically change that and would not cause error.
But it's annoying.

Anyway to solve?
Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like you put `local.properties` into the Git repo, which is not recommended.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a this answer:
[What should be in my .gitignore for an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)
Look for this part: # Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)

Basically you need to set up a git ignore file.