# Commit Folder Android Studio Project

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Not all folder in project uploaded to github as default. Is it ok?

such folder build not uploading to git as default. any reference about it? should I leave it or including folder build too?

How to do that?

Thank you

Comment: there is one file .gitignore in your project.. just decide what you want to upload and what not and,  add name of file or folder to that file. it is not necessary to add build in commit becoz every time it will generate this folder whenever you build the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `build/` is part of `.gitignore` that is why it's not been uploaded on remote. This is perfectly fine.

Even if you wish to include it into remote repository.

- `git rm --cached .`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "Message of your choice"`
- `git push origin branch_name`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Your information so helpful

Comment: @andrewkusuma : Please accept this answer, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android projects now are created with a .gitignore file. [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore. So one of the files that are specified in gitignore is the build folder. Therefore when you commit, it doesn't get uploaded to git as default. You should leave it alone but if you want to, you can simply remove the build folder specified in .gitignore.

You can also look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project) as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: No problem! Hopefully it helped.