# Should I version app/build files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, versioning, gitignore

I'm new to Git and Android development and I could not find an answer to this question.

When I build a project in Android Studio a lot of files are created in the folder `app/build`.

I guess I don't need that files, but before ignoring them in the `.gitignore`, I would like to be sure to not mess my repo since from the first commit :D

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project), but I cannot see in the example `.gitignore` the folder `app/build`.

Should I add it to my `.gitignore`?

P.S. I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3, if relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess I don't need that files, but before ignoring them in the .gitignore I would like to be sure to not mess my repo since from the first commit :D

You don't need `build` files in your repo.

Usually `.gitignore` file contains `/build`.

> I checked this question but I cannot see in the example .gitignore the folder app/build.

You can place another one `.gitignore` file to `app` directory, the content of this file also contains `/build`.

```
/project
     .gitignore
     /app
         .gitignore
```

Comment: Ok, this is weird. If I copy/past the example `.gitignore` (which contains `build/` ) in the `app/` folder, build files are not ignored. Same result if I add `/app/build/`,`/*/build/` or `app/build/`.

Comment: Android studio uses this approach:) Try creating a new project to check

Comment: >If I copy/past the example .gitignore (which contains build/ ) in the app/ folder, build files are not ignored. That's not right

Comment: I see some `.gitignore` ignoring the entire `.idea` folder, some only few files like `.idea/workspace.xml` or folders  like `.idea/libraries`. Which is the correct approach?

Comment: I prefer ignoring whole `.idea` folder.

Answer (score 2):

> If I copy/past the example `.gitignore` (which contains `build/` ) in the `app/` folder, build files are not ignored.

That would be because those files are already tracked.

Try:

```
cd app
git rm --cached -r build/
git add .
git commit -m "record build content deletion"
git push
```

Then `app/build` will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) for generating gitignore files