# What files should be in my .gitignore for my Android Intellij project?

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

I have an android app that I've checked into git. I am using Intellij. I've run into issues with some of the files (paths are for a different machine) when I work on a different machine than the one I originally created the application on.

Which files can I safely include in my gitignore? I saw the post for [AndroidStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project); are there any additional files that I should be aware for for Intellij?

Does the editor matter when determining which files I put in my gitignore?

Comment: For intellij/android studio, i ignore anything in `/.idea`, as well as any `*.iml` and `*.iws` files

Comment: Everything in build.

Comment: @torkleyy ah, I didn't see that question

Comment: @torkleyy that question was specifically for eclipse though

Comment: @sparkyShorts yes it was but the answer seems to be very complete

Comment: A good place to start is [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/)

Comment: For machine-specific ignores, you can add files to `.git/info/exclude` (but you have to do this on each machine).

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Git backup files
*.orig

# generated files
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db

# OSX files
.DS_Store

# Android Studio
.idea/*
.gradle/*
build/*
*.iml
gradle.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Sample Android Project: Google](https://github.com/codepath/intro_android_demo/blob/master/.gitignore)

This file is taken from the Sample Android Projects repo by Google.

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/
proguard-project.txt

# Intellij project files
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
.gradle
build/**
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# Android Studio project files
*.iml
.gradle
.idea
build
import-summary.txt
```

Comment: I don't think that including `bin/` is a good idea - I use this folder for project-specific scripts, which definitely need to be tracked.

Comment: @Vasiliy `bin/` is generally used by build systems for temporary or intermediate files and other artifacts. I would not recommend it as a place to store important files. You are better off creating a separate folder (e.g. `scripts` or `tools`) to house your scripts and track that instead.