# Build gradle will changed other file in android and it cause conflict when git pull

Tags: android, git, build, android-gradle-plugin

[image: This file i never changed it but it always changed when run the app]

The problem is when i want pull from git , i need to commit first. I just commit few file that i made change but still can't pull because it detect this generated build file is changed so i commit all file then when i pull then it will be a conflict. Need to rebuild but sometimes it take long time, sometimes need to invalidate and restart. But sometimes the project can't run again.. How can i prevent this problem ?

Comment: Please paste text errors which makes it easy for other devs to highlight parts - NOT images, which only make everyone else user more bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about how to use Git Ignore files - things listed in gitignore are not synced.

Intermediates and any other files in the build directory should not be added to version control.

This is a great starting point for what contents should be in your gitignore file:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

I stole it vertabim from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17803964/984830), so you can find additional information there

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `git stash` command before git pull. That command will save your local changes and clean working directory. You could always bring back saved changes (e.g., after git pull is finished) using `git stash pop` command. See `git help stash` for details