# What is a legit .gitignore for a Flutter project that is developed in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

What is a legit .gitignore for a Flutter project that is developed in Android Studio?

This is what I have so far, but when I open up the project in Android Studio I am unable to enable Dart Support or browse the project.

```
#flutter specific
.flutter-plugins
.DS_Store
.dart_tool/
.packages
.pub/
build/
android/app/google-services.json
.idea/
android/key.properties
pubspec.lock
doc/api/

#ios specific
ios/.generated/
ios/Podfile*
ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig
ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig
ios/Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata

#android specific
android/app/google-services.json
android/key.properties

# User-specific
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/*.iml
.idea/modules
*.iml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/
```

Comment: Have you tried gitignore.io? There are usually some pretty sane defaults there: https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,flutter,androidstudio

Comment: When you create a new Flutter project a `.gitignore` file is created already. What's wrong with that file? This file is not related to "enable Dart support".

Comment: Your  problem with "enabling Dart support" is because of the .idea in your .gitignore. .idea has codeStyle that makes Android Studio recognize your project as a dart project. Also check [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13892) about making a .gitignore for flutter projects.

Comment: Shall the `*.g.dart` be ignored?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This is the .gitignore generated automatically by Android Studio, hope that this is what you're looking for:

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
```

Comment: Shall the `*.g.dart` be ignored?

Comment: Shouldn't pubspec.lock also be ignored?

Comment: It should be commited for applications: "For application packages, do commit pubspec.lock. This file is the recommended way for non-shared resources such as applications to manage their dependencies."
https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files

Comment: For library packages, don’t commit the pubspec.lock file. Regenerating the pubspec.lock file lets you test your package against the latest compatible versions of its dependencies.
See https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files#pubspeclock for more info.

Comment: gradlew seems to need to be checked in version control, instead of gitignored. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954932/should-i-gitignore-my-gradlew

Answer (score 17):

You can find it in official project of flutter on [Github here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore):

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code related
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.vscode/

# Flutter repo-specific
/bin/cache/
/bin/internal/bootstrap.bat
/bin/internal/bootstrap.sh
/bin/mingit/
/dev/benchmarks/mega_gallery/
/dev/bots/.recipe_deps
/dev/bots/android_tools/
/dev/devicelab/ABresults*.json
/dev/docs/doc/
/dev/docs/flutter.docs.zip
/dev/docs/lib/
/dev/docs/pubspec.yaml
/dev/integration_tests/**/xcuserdata
/dev/integration_tests/**/Pods
/packages/flutter/coverage/
version
analysis_benchmark.json

# packages file containing multi-root paths
.packages.generated

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
**/generated_plugin_registrant.dart
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/
flutter_*.png
linked_*.ds
unlinked.ds
unlinked_spec.ds

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties
*.jks

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/ephemeral
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# macOS
**/macos/Flutter/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.swift

# Coverage
coverage/

# Symbols
app.*.symbols

# Exceptions to above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
!/dev/ci/**/Gemfile.lock
```

Here just some points to note when making changes on `.gitgnore` file to ensure Git is always tracking the right files.

1. Make changes in `.gitignore` file.
2. Run `git rm -r --cached .` command.
3. Run `git add .` command

Comment: I think that this is not meant to be included in Flutter projects. Just think that all .lock files are ignored...

Answer (score 9):

VSCode provides this and is equally good as the android studio version

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release
```

Answer (score 7):

**Here is Consistent** `.gitignore` **for Dart and Flutter projects all Editors**

- Android Studio
- VisualStudioCode
- Xcode

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13892#issue-285842688

Answer (score 1):

Here is a legit .gitignore for Flutter 2.2 taken from [Very Good Core](https://verygood.ventures/solution/very-good-start) cli

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.lock
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/*

# Visual Studio Code related
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.vscode/*

# Flutter repo-specific
/bin/cache/
/bin/mingit/
/dev/benchmarks/mega_gallery/
/dev/bots/.recipe_deps
/dev/bots/android_tools/
/dev/docs/doc/
/dev/docs/flutter.docs.zip
/dev/docs/lib/
/dev/docs/pubspec.yaml
/dev/integration_tests/**/xcuserdata
/dev/integration_tests/**/Pods
/packages/flutter/coverage/
version

# packages file containing multi-root paths
.packages.generated

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
build/
flutter_*.png
linked_*.ds
unlinked.ds
unlinked_spec.ds
.fvm/

# Android related
**/android/**/gradle-wrapper.jar
**/android/.gradle
**/android/captures/
**/android/gradlew
**/android/gradlew.bat
**/android/local.properties
**/android/**/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
**/android/key.properties
**/android/.idea/
*.jks

# iOS/XCode related
**/ios/**/*.mode1v3
**/ios/**/*.mode2v3
**/ios/**/*.moved-aside
**/ios/**/*.pbxuser
**/ios/**/*.perspectivev3
**/ios/**/*sync/
**/ios/**/.sconsign.dblite
**/ios/**/.tags*
**/ios/**/.vagrant/
**/ios/**/DerivedData/
**/ios/**/Icon?
**/ios/**/Pods/
**/ios/**/.symlinks/
**/ios/**/profile
**/ios/**/xcuserdata
**/ios/.generated/
**/ios/Flutter/App.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
**/ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
**/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
**/ios/Flutter/app.flx
**/ios/Flutter/app.zip
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/
**/ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
**/ios/ServiceDefinitions.json
**/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Coverage
coverage/

# Submodules
!pubspec.lock
packages/**/pubspec.lock

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Exceptions to the above rules.
!**/ios/**/default.mode1v3
!**/ios/**/default.mode2v3
!**/ios/**/default.pbxuser
!**/ios/**/default.perspectivev3
!/packages/flutter_tools/test/data/dart_dependencies_test/**/.packages
!/dev/ci/**/Gemfile.lock
!.vscode/launch.json
!.idea/codeStyles/
!.idea/dictionaries/
!.idea/runConfigurations/
```

Answer (score -1):

`.gitignore` below excludes all files and folders except: `lib/, pubspec.yaml and AndroidManifest.xml` i.e. only manually changed files:

```
.dart_tool
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.gitignore
.idea
.metadata
.vscode

build
assets

#ignore android except android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
android/*
!android/app
android/app/*
!android/app/src
android/app/src/*
!android/app/src/main
android/app/src/main/*
!android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml


ios
linux
macos
web
windows
README.md
pubspec.lock
```

Only for local use. If you publish to Github or another shared repository use the default file.