# Which files to upload to version control from a Flutter project?

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter, version-control, gitignore

I want to upload my Flutter projects to Github.

But, I don't know which files or folders should I upload and which I should add to the **.gitignore** file!

**Here are the Folders:**

- .dart_tool
- .idea
- android
- build
- images
- ios
- lib

**Here are the Files:**

- .gitignore
- .metadata
- .packages
- i_am_rich.iml
- pubspec.lock
- pubspec.yaml
- README.md

So, which Folders and Files?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286143/what-is-a-legit-gitignore-for-a-flutter-project-that-is-developed-in-android-st

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a legit .gitignore for a Flutter project that is developed in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286143/what-is-a-legit-gitignore-for-a-flutter-project-that-is-developed-in-android-st)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking folder by folder

1) `.dart_tool` is generated, you don't need to push it

2) `.idea`, never push this folder, it's generated by your IDE

3) `.package`, it'll be generated when you install dependencies, no need to push it

4) `i_am_ruch.iml`, IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA, no need to push it

5) `pubspec.lock` is generated by `pub`, you don't need to push it

6) `build` folder is generated during the project's build

So finally, you must **push** the `android`, `lib`, `ios`, `images`, `.gitignore`, `pubspec.yaml` and `README.md`

- `ios`, `android` folder contains native code and configuration for each platform
- `lib` contains you flutter code
- `images`, I guess it's resources
- `pubspec.yaml` contains dependencies to install during `pub get`, and some project configuration

If you want the perfect flutter' gitignore: [here it is](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore) (from official Flutter Github Repository)

Comment: If you're working on a application (not a library), you should definitely version control `pubspec.lock`. This way other developers will make sure they're using the same lib versions.