# Auto generating files by flutter run

Tags: flutter

Each time I run my project GitKraken detects 6 files which I didn't add as you can see [image: here]

[image: This screenshot shows the files generated]

What is the reason for regenerating these files each time I run the project and how to solve it?

Comment: Could you show us which files?

Comment: I added screenshot showing the files

Answer (score 0):

You should add `**/android/.gradle` to your `.gitignore`. For a detailed example for flutter check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991978/6704033

Comment: When I added that to .gitignore and re-run the app it was the same nothing changed.

Comment: @Addow maybe re-open GitKraken, or reboot your computer? Or maybe share the content of your `.gitignore`