# Unique files in the project that should not be found in the GitHub

Tags: android, github

1. Which files I should push to GitHub from Android project and which shouln't push ? Only src ? Now I can't run with only srv this app after clone from GitHub.
2. After first share on GitHub, now I can't share again with other files, Now I can share only again only srv, how to reset it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be in my .gitignore for an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project)

Comment: it is not duplicate, check my 2 question