# How can I make Android studio "forget" old filepaths when I copy an old project?

Tags: android-studio

Scenario:

1. I'm working through the exercises in an Android programming book.
2. I finish "Chapter 10", so I "Close Project" and exit Android Studio, manually delete build/* and copy "chap10" to a new folder, "chap11".
3. I start Android Studio > Open Existing Project > chap11.

   So far, so good.  Everything looks fine.
4. I start editing a .java source file or .xml layout file in chap11 ... and Android Studio overwrites the old files in the old directory instead (?!?)

Q: What causes this behavior?

Q: What can I do to make Android Studio "forget" everything about the old "chap10", and use *ONLY* filepaths from the new "chap11" instead?

I'm using Android Studio 3.5, Build: Aug 8, 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here.  After copying the directory, I delete all of the following (and let Android Studio recreate them on gradle build):

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24679853/421195
>
> ```
> app/build/*
> .gradle/*
> .idea/*
> *.iml
> local.properties
> ```
>
> I think almost everyone agrees about /build.
>
> I got sick of constantly seeing messages about the various library.xml
>   files that Gradle creates or deletes in /.idea. The build.gradle will
>   run on the developers's local when they first check out the project,
>   so why do those XML files need to be versioned? Android Studio will
>   also generate the rest of /.idea when a developer creates a project
>   using Check out from Version Control, so why does anything in that
>   folder need to be versioned?
>
> If the *.iml is versioned a new user will have to name the project
>   exactly the same as it was when committed. Since this is also a
>   generated file, why version it in the first place?
>
> The local.properties files points to an absolute path on the file
>   system for the SDK, so it definitely shouldn't be versioned.