# What is the different between /build and build/ in gitignore?

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I notice the recommendation for .gitignore for Android in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17803964/3286489 have both `/build` and `build/`. What are their differences? Should we have both, or just one will do?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/build` is what I like to call an *anchored* name.  It matches the file or directory name `build` at the level of the tree where the `.gitignore` resides.  So this excludes `/build`, whether it is a file or directory, but not `abc/build`, whether that is a file or directory.

Meanwhile, `build/` is *not* anchored, so it matches at any level of the tree here or below.  It does however have a trailing slash, so it only matches *directories* (or folders if you prefer that word) named `build`.  So if there is an `abc/build` or `def/ghi/build`, it is matched if and only if it is a directory.

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation. I assume `build/` also cover the root directory `/build` folder, right?

Comment: Yes, if the top level `build` is a directory, `build/` would cover it.

Comment: @torek can we think it like when declaring it as "/build" -> *.{file,dir} in root level  will be ignored where as when we define "build/"  it can be thought as "**/*.{file,dir} ?  

Just showing the prior ones denotes at top level and latter one at any level of deep it will work

Comment: @khizer: I like to use the adjective *anchored* for several reasons: (1) That same adjective is used in regular expressions. While REs are not glob patterns, they are related (glob expressions are in effect extremely-limited REs). (2) In a `.gitignore` entry, `a/b/` is also anchored, having the same meaning as `/a/b/`, but `a/` is *not* anchored, having a different meaning than `/a/`. So our first task, upon reading a non-comment `.gitignore` line, is to discover whether it is anchored and/or negated and/or flagged as "applies only to directories". After that, we can determine what it does.

Comment: A *non-anchored pattern* is "floating", so it will match at any level (here or below that is). An *anchored* pattern cannot float down to some other level: it matches here, or does not match.

Comment: Meanwhile, the *trailing* slash in "build/" or "/build/"—the former is not anchored, and the latter is anchored, due to the *prefix* slash—sets the "applies only to a directory" flag. That is, this particular `.gitignore` entry matches a directory, but does not match a file. The "directory only, or directory-and-file-both" flag is *independent of* the anchored flag. So it's sensible to interpret each up front, and only then begin to concern ourselves with which names match.