# Files to ignore while using Android Studio with Git or Mercurial

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-studio

I am using Android Studio with Gradle.

Could somebody help me to figure out what files should I add to ignore list in my Git repository?

At the time I have following in the ignore file

```
.gradle
*.idea/workspace.xml
ProjectName/.idea/workspace.xml
ProjectName/ModuleName/build/
```

but I am not sure if above is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640566/which-files-shouldnt-be-checked-in-into-version-control-in-android-studio